# Varnish removes Public IP from X-Forwarded-for

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

I am facing an issue where varnish is not sending Intermediary proxy IP or Public IP in a particular case. 
Scenario is as below :

- Some Hotel / Company has squid proxy configured and all traffic for Internet is routed via Squid.
- User accessing my company's site first hits the Load Balancer then Varnish  & then Apache
- Apache is configured with mod_geoip. The code on my site does the Country redirection based on the IP address.

Problem :

- When an user (Behind that squid proxy) accessing my company's website behind Load Balancer -> VARNISH -> Apache  - Here apache gets only Internal IP (His Private IP) & Load Balancer Internal IP as X-forwarded-for and Hence the IP based redirection FAILS!

In Apache logs (Configured to log X-Forwarded-IP) I see that Users Private IP & then My Load Balancers Private IP.

172.10.5.10, LoadBalancerIP - - [.......]

- The same user when accesses another site which does NOT have Varnish, hits Load Balancer -> Apache - Here apache gets Users Private IP & Users Public IP as X-forwarded-for and IP based country redirection works fine.

In Apache logs (Configured to log X-Forwarded-IP) I see that Users Private IP and then his Public IP is also logged.

172.10.5.10, PublicIP - - [.......]

My Varnish Config is as below.

```
       if (req.restarts == 0) {
                   if (req.http.x-forwarded-for) {
                 set req.http.X-Forwarded-For =
                     req.http.X-Forwarded-For + ", " + client.ip;
                   } else {
                 set req.http.X-Forwarded-For = client.ip;
                   }
           }
```

PS: I've already Google'd all links I could find and every link gives the following Varnish Config

For now to get this issue resolved, I had to bypass varnish and now website traffic is directly hitting Apache but I need to get Varnish back in place to server content from Cache and Speedy delivery.

Will appreciate if someone can guide me to how resolve this issue.

Thanks!

Comment: Hello, I've gathered Varnish logs for the above mentioned issue and have pasted @ http://pastebin.ca/2353444

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above mentioned issue has been resolved. Credit goes to Mithrandir @ Varnish IRC Channel. Thanks!
Below mentioned changes were required to resolve the issue.

At the start of the default.vcl add :

```
import std;
```

Below  " if (req.http.x-forwarded-for) " add :

```
std.collect(req.http.x-forwarded-for);
```

- Do varnish configtest & reload. This should start showing the Public IP.
- Below is the explanation from the documentation of vmod_std :

> collect
>
> ```
>    Prototype
>           collect(HEADER header)
>
>    Return value
>           Void
>
>    Description
>           Collapses the header, joining the headers into one.
>
>    Example
>           std.collect(req.http.cookie); This will collapse several Cookie:
>           headers into one, long cookie header.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

In Varnish 4 this is not needed anymore, [see upgrade info here](https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/4.0/whats-new/upgrading.html#x-forwarded-for-is-now-set-before-vcl-recv)